# Virtual hosts stoped working (dnsmasq, apache)

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, virtualhost, dnsmasq

Few months ago I've set up my local web development environment following this guide: http://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/
Everything worked perfectly until yesterday and I have no idea what happened. I can ping my *.dev addresses:

```
➜ ping -c 1 home.dev
PING home.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms

--- home.dev ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.049/0.049/0.049/0.000 ms
```

but when I try to type the address into my browser all I got is error msg

> This site can’t be reached
>
> home.dev refused to connect.

I've restarted my computer, dnasmq and apache like hundred times, I've repeated all steps from linked guide (and I've also tried this one: https://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/) but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

My setup:

**http-vhosts.conf file:**

```
<Directory "/www">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/home/wwwroot"
  ServerName home.dev
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/wwwroot"
  ServerName sites.dev
  ServerAlias *.dev
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%-7+/wwwroot"
  ServerName xip
  ServerAlias *.xip.io
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

**Folder structure:**

- /www

  - home

    - wwwroot
    - index.html
    - (...)
  - sites

    - sites
    - test

      - wwwroot
      - index.html
      - (...)

**httpd -S command:**

```
➜ httpd -S
[Mon Jan 15 16:53:36.655895 2018] [so:warn] [pid 31755] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using olivetum.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server home.dev (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:7)
         port 80 namevhost home.dev (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:7)
         port 80 namevhost sites.dev (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:13)
                 wild alias *.dev
         port 80 namevhost xip (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:20)
                 wild alias *.xip.io
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

**dig home.dev @127.0.0.1 command:**

```
➜ dig home.dev @127.0.0.1
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;home.dev.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
home.dev.       0   IN  A   127.0.0.1
```